# I have 2 DHCP servers on same network, I have to do dhcp release on secondary AP to connect to the main router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I have a main router from ISP - 192.168.1.1, dhcp enabled, range 33-127.
I have connected a secondary router(tp link) as an AP - 192.168.1.2, dhcp enabled, range 128-254.

Why ?
because when i disable dhcp on secondary router it fails to assign IP addresses.

Now the Problem -
I connect to main router with windows 10. it works.( ip for example 192.168.1.34)
Then i connect to secondary router. it works ( ip for example 192.168.128)
Then i connect back to main router. It connects. Ping works. but cannot make a request. (ip - 192.168.1.34 - same as before)

I connect back to secondary router. I do ipconfig /release.
Then connect back to main router. It works.

Also, my iphone is able to switch between those 2 networks seemlessly with proper ip according to range.

how to fix this ?
any alternative on how to run only 1 dhcp to to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a main router from ISP - 192.168.1.1, dhcp enabled, range
> 33-127. I have connected a secondary router(tp link) as an AP -
> 192.168.1.2, dhcp enabled, range 128-254. how to fix this ? any alternative on how to run only 1 dhcp to to fix this ?

Yes.

In a small network like this, you really need just one DHCP server. More than one causes issues as you see.

1. Connect a LAN port (not WAN port) on the secondary Access point to a LAN port on the main router.
2. Give the Access Point a static IP on the main network. That is, an address on the main network that is not in the main network DHCP range.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the Access point.

Now you have one DHCP server, everything is on the same subnet, and you should not have any conflicts.

I have my own network set up this way and do this for other customers as well.

Your Access Point should be configurable enough to get you on one subnet.  If for whatever reason the Access Point is not flexible enough, you may need a different, more configurable Access Point.

Comment: As i have said the secondary AP fails to give IP configuration to devices connected to it if i turn DHCP off.  


I have given it a static IP of 192.168.1.2   
the main router has 192.168.1.1  
DHCP off on secondary router. connected LAN to LAN via ethernet cable.

Comment: I have given it a static IP of 192.168.1.2 the main router has 192.168.1.1 DHCP   <-- So you appear now to have one subnet and that should work. You may need a better Access Point to solve your issue if the current one is not flexible enough.

Comment: Its a tp link TL-WR840N, i have bought it new. I am sure its flexible enough as it is a relatively new model.

Comment: You should be able to set that up as I posted. Perhaps do a factory reset of the Access Point and then set it up as shown.